# Is there a Laravel hasManyThrough equivalent for getting another parent model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My models are set up as follows:

```
Alpha hasMany Gamma
Beta hasMany Gamma
Gamma belongsTo Alpha
Gamma belongsTo Beta
```

Now, let's say I have an Alpha object. I want to get all Betas that have Gamma objects in common with the Alpha object. Is there a good Laravel way of doing this?

I can think of one workaround:

```
// getting an ids list (L5.1 syntax)
$beta_ids = $alpha->gammas()->groupBy('beta_id')->lists('beta_id')->all();
$bets = Beta::whereIn('id', $beta_ids);
```

But this feels quite a lot like a hack. Is there an appropriate Laravel way?

Comment: have you try to use ```has``` or ```with```?

Comment: @jycr753 Thank you for replying. I don't really see how either of those would help, but if you have any suggestions I would be happy to see them.

Answer (score 1):

Your way if not so hacky and quite readable. I would consider avoiding grouping as it can be quite an expensive operation. Duplicated ids in whereIn() should not be a big drag performance-wise.

If you still want an alternative one-liner then i guess you could do something like this:

```
$betas = $alpha->gammas->whereHas('beta')->get()->transform(function($gamma) { return $gamma->beta; });
```

Transform() will go through every element and return an element as defined in anonymous function. Keep in mind that this will execute more sql queries than the first solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping there was a shorthand method for it already, but I guess not. Not using group by is a good tip, thanks.